# Start application with second activity

Tags: android, android-activity

In my android app, When user have successfully login with Facebook and Google Plus then user have one confirmation Activity which have next button in disable mode.  While, admin will be enable user from database. If user will be enable from database by admin then confirmation Activity and next button will be enable and user can move to next Activity. When user open app in second time then user will be able to show the confirmation Activity.

I don't know, how to apply this logic :

**Scenario:**

First Scene:

```
Splash screen->Login->success->confirmation activity
```

Second Scene:

```
ConfirmationActivty->Next button enable
```

Comment: Can you add some of your code. What your asking is pretty simple, but I need to know how you build it

Comment: No because I don't have any logic I want logic for second screen how to open second screen when user click on second time then user will be able to see second screen in android. @Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `SplashActivity.java` is your main activity

Change your code as shown below

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    SharedPreferences preferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPreference", MODE_PRIVATE);

        // returns true if value does not exist
        // if it's users first time this will return true
        if( preferences.getBoolean  ("isFirstTime", true)){
            prefEditor = preferences.edit();
            // changes the value
            prefEditor.putBoolean("isFirstTime", false).commit();
        }else{

            // add your code to open your Confirmation Activity
            finish();
            return;
        }

        // rest of your code including `setContentView()`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the visibility of "next" button to "GONE" and make a network call in the background to your server to check if the admin has approved or not. If approved, you can set the visibility of the button to "VISIBLE". And during the network call you can start a progress dialog.Click [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/DemonstratesmakingaviewVISIBLEINVISIBLEandGONE.htm) to see how to use visibility.

[**Update**]
you can use something like:

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
            Constants.LAUNCH_TIME_PREFERENCE_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = prefs.edit();
    profile = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Constants.PROFILE_PREFERENCE_FILE,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (!prefs.getBoolean(Constants.FIRST_TIME,false)) {
        // <---- run your one time code here
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,first_screen.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        startActivity(intent);


    }
```

Comment: I apply this logic it's work perfect but when user open app second time then user show confirmation activity in android actually, In my case when user open app second time then splash screen is available but i want confirmation activity. @Anshuman Agrawal

Comment: @Richa use SharedPreferences and check if user is opening your App first time or not in `onCreate()` of your splash screen before calling `setContentView()`. if not open Confirmation Activity and finish Splash and return. Post some code we can review and change

Comment: can you provide some source code structure please @Prashant

Comment: @Richa see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreferences, or File or Database for user's history data and check if the user fulfill your criteria. Then you can let him move from one activity to another. Check these links 
[SharedPreferences Totorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html)

[SQLite & Content Providers](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

**For First Scene :**

You should set flag i.e `isUserLoggedIn` in preferences which will false by default. 
After user logged in, set this flag to true.
In `LoginActivity` `onCreate()`, check that flag from preferences, if it is true finish the activity and start `confirmationActivity` else do nothing.

**For Second Scene :**

Here, you can also maintain the flag `isUserConfirmed` same as for login. And you can send notification from server to the user, after receiving notification update the flag to true. And enable the button on `ConfirmationActivity` if the activity is in the foreground.